# как сделать что бы при выходе картинки за пределы блока, она там не отображалась?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть картинка, которая выходит за пределы блока, как сделать что бы та часть которая выходит за пределы блока не отображалась, т.е. картинка как бы обрубалась?

Comment: overflow:hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В стилях родительского элемента *(предположим, он имеет класс parent)*

```
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Либо можно не создавать CSS файл, написать напрямую в HTML:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <img src="image.jpg">
<div>
```

*P.S.: Хорошей практикой считается первый вариант*

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли, никак не мог найти.